# How to remove black background off raster images?

Tags: qgis

I am having trouble with QGIS 3.4. I have just added a raster layer of a JPEG image of an island I have stitched together, however on QGIS it is displayed with a black background around the edge. I would like to remove this, I understand I might have to reclass the data?

Is it showing up as black as there is no data?

Comment: Do you want to remove the black area, or simply make it transparent?

Comment: Look at this part of the QGIS documentation : https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html#transparency-properties